# Weak*convergence Problem

Tags: functional-analysis

I have the following exercise:
$\pi_n : \ell^{\infty}\rightarrow \ell^{\infty},x\mapsto \pi_n(x)$, where $(\pi_n(x))_k=x_k$ for $0\leq k\leq n$ and $(\pi_n(x))_k=0$ for $k>n$. We claim that the sequence $(\pi_n(x))_n$ is weak*convergent to x.

So, one solution that I have takes an $y\in \ell^1$ and it identifies it in $(\ell^{1})^{**}$ using the canonical embedding $i(y)$ and states:

$$\langle i(y),\pi_n(x) \rangle = \langle \pi_n(x),y \rangle = \sum_{1\leq k\leq n}{x_ky_k},$$ which is absolutely convergent to $$\langle i(y),x \rangle = \langle x,y \rangle.$$

My problems are:

Why can I identify elements in the dual of the space using the embedding? This is not bijective, so there may be an element in the dual that will not taken by an y. And so I would have a problem with the definition of w*convergence. And moreover... Why is the sum absolutely convergent to $\langle x,y \rangle$?

Comment: If $X$ is a normed space, a sequence $(x'_n)$ of functionals is weak*-convergent iff $(x'_n(x))$ converges for all $x\in X$. Absolute convergence follows from the Hölder inequality.

Comment: Ok absolute convergence is now ok. Still have trouble with the identification problem. There is also another definition: $x_n$ converges weakl * to $x$ $\iff$ $f(x_n)\rightarrow f(x) \forall f\in X^{**}$

Comment: That definition describes *weak* convergence, not weak-*.  For weak convergence, you are required to have $f(x_n) \to f(x)$ for all $f$ in the dual space.  For weak-\*, you are only required to have it for those $f$ that correspond to elements of the predual.

Comment: But then if it is so why the statement was proved like this?